# Sonar Findbugs not running

Tags: sonarqube

i have installed sonar and executing sonar-runner from my parent folder but i get the following error do any anyone have an idea what to do?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not execute Findbugs
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:288)
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:84)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not execute Findbugs
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:126)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsSensor.analyse(FindbugsSensor.java:62)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:93)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:139)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:131)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:104)
    at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.executeBatch(Launcher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:285)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: File '/home/bldarea/example/dev/archive/.sonar/findbugs-result.xml' cannot be written to
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openOutputStream(FileUtils.java:228)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:95)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear: the 'findbugs-result.xml' temporary file can't be written on the disk, in the folder '/home/bldarea/example/dev/archive/.sonar'.

So you have to know why this file can't be written there. This may be linked to user rights or user quota on this folder...